# Error querying database in PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in PHP. It connects to the DB fine, but pops an error, when tryinto to insert the info.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'marina', 'aliendatabase') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email) VALUSE ('John', 'john@everynet.gov')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Here's a screenshot: http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/2930/63306356.jpg

Thanks,
R

Comment: `die('Error querying database.')`-> `trigger_error(mysqli_error().$query);`

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us **which** error you get :)

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rob\report.php on line 43

Notice: INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email) VALUES ('John', 'john@everynet.gov') in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rob\report.php on line 43

Comment: @user296516: Can you also post the corresponding code? It seems that you try to call `mysqli_error()` without passing any parameter. In the code you have given currently there is no `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: >>> It seems that you try to call mysqli_error() without passing any parameter.
I just replaced die('Error querying database.') with trigger_error(mysqli_error().$query); as Col. Shrapnel suggested above.
While the initial error I am getting is "Error querying database." , therefor there should be something wrong with this two lines.
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email) VALUES ('John', 'john@everynet.gov')";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

Comment: @user296516: You have to use it this way: `mysqli_error($dbc)`.

Comment: Tried it with or trigger_error(mysqli_error($dbc)); it shows Notice: Field 'when_did_it_happen' doesn't have a default value in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rob\report.php on line 43

Comment: GOT IT WORKING! appears it didn't like that I did not give valuses to all fields - Field 'when_did_it_happen' doesn't have a default value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email) VALUES ('John', 'john@everynet.gov')";
```

Comment: edited the typo, thanks. but still the same error keeps popping. :/

Answer (score 3):

seems that you've misspelled VALUES in your query.

Comment: edited the typo, thanks. but still the same error keeps popping. :/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email, when_did_it_happen, what_did_they_do, " . "seen_Fang", "anything_else") VALUES ($'name', '$email', '$when_did_it_happen',". "'$what_did_they_do', '$seen_Fang', '$anything_else')";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your query. Try changing `VALUSE` to `VALUES`.

Comment: edited the typo, thanks. but still the same error keeps popping. :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write something along the lines of...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (name, email, when_did_it_happen, what_did_they_do, " .
"seen_Fang", "anything_else") VALUES ('John', 'john@everynet.gov', 'tuesday', 'nothing', 'no', ' ')";
```

When you insert data into the table, you need to specify every row you have in that table in the brackets before the Values...

By now you have probably found out the answer for yourself :P However for others that may have a similar error (such as myself) may find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same exercise from **Headfirst PHP & MYSQL** and got the same error and figured out why this happened. In my end, this happened just because I had filled one of the form field with a text containing **apostrophe** ( **'** ). I have circled that text in Red color in below screenshot. Hope this helps someone to go ahead.
[image]

and also explanation and sample codes in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) will help you to display error messages relevant to the errors in your code.